# Can Service return types be mixed, using both START_STICKY and START_REDELIVER_INTENT depending on action?

Tags: android, android-service

Can onStartCommand() return types be mixed depending on the action? For example, a Service that stays started with START_STICKY, but always gets the first intent redelivered to maintain state.

This would be especially useful when the initial intent contains things that aren't easily persisted such as a PendingIntent.

It seems to work but I can't find documentation and I worry there could be unexpected behavior. The documentation does suggest that a service using START_REDELIVER_INTENT may not be kept running in the same way as one using START_STICKY, but its a bit unclear.

> START_STICKY is used for services that are explicitly started and
>   stopped as needed, while START_NOT_STICKY or START_REDELIVER_INTENT
>   are used for services that should only remain running while processing
>   any commands sent to them

Here is an example of a service that could handle various requests without providing the initial state, but making sure its available.

```
private PendingIntent pendingIntent;
private Config config;

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    if (intent != null) {
        switch (intent.getAction()) {

            case ACTION_START:
                // save state
                config = intent.getParcelableExtra("config");
                pendingIntent = intent.getParcelableExtra("pendingIntent");
                return START_REDELIVER_INTENT;

            case ACTION_STOP:
                stopSelf();
                return START_NOT_STICKY;

            case ACTION_SOME_TASK:
                // caller does not have state but it needs to be loaded here
                doSomething();
                break;

            case ACTION_SOME_OTHER_TASK:
                doSomethingElse();
                break;
        }
    }
    return START_STICKY;
}
```